# Go: cast slice of primitive to a slice of its alias

Tags: casting, go, alias

I'm trying to do something along these lines:

```
package main                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

import (          
    "fmt"         
)                 

type StringWrap string

func main() {     
    s := []string{"a","b","c"}
    sw := []StringWrap(s) //ERROR: cannot convert s (type []string) to type []StringWrap
    fmt.Println(sw)
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this simply a limitation in go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Types)
>
> A type determines the set of values and operations specific to values
>   of that type. A type may be specified by a (possibly qualified) type
>   name or a type literal, which composes a new type from previously
>   declared types.
>
> ```
> Type      = TypeName | TypeLit | "(" Type ")" .
> TypeName  = identifier | QualifiedIdent .
> TypeLit   = ArrayType | StructType | PointerType | FunctionType |
>             InterfaceType | SliceType | MapType | ChannelType .
> ```
>
> Named instances of the boolean, numeric, and string types are
>   predeclared. Composite types—array, struct, pointer, function,
>   interface, slice, map, and channel types—may be constructed using type
>   literals.
>
> Each type `T` has an underlying type: If `T` is a predeclared type or a
>   type literal, the corresponding underlying type is `T` itself.
>   Otherwise, `T`'s underlying type is the underlying type of the type to
>   which `T` refers in its type declaration.
>
> ```
>    type T1 string
>    type T2 T1
>    type T3 []T1
>    type T4 T3
> ```
>
> The underlying type of `string`, `T1`, and `T2` is `string`. The underlying
>   type of `[]T1`, `T3`, and `T4` is `[]T1`.
>
> [Conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions are expressions of the form `T(x)` where `T` is a type and
>   `x` is an expression that can be converted to type `T`.
>
> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in the case:
>   `x`'s type and `T` have identical underlying types.

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type StringSliceWrap []string

func main() {
    s := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    ssw := StringSliceWrap(s)
    fmt.Println(ssw)
}
```

Output:

```
[a b c]
```